# PHP / MySQLi - Select from 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to query 2 databases that are on 2 servers? So I'd have 2 connections like this:

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.1","my_user","my_password","db1");
$con2 = mysqli_connect("123.456.7.8","my_user","my_password","db2");
```

But I'm then not sure how the query would work, because I normally use the connection to query the database:

```
$con1->query("SELECT...");
```

Is it possible to connect to 2 databases in the same connection?

Comment: Have you tried it ?

Comment: This post is a duplication of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10257091/935330 and not the above.